# Django Rest Framework: urls with multiple slugs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I am develping the API for my blog. Every articles is related to a category, then the url of an articles is like this: `"<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_post>/"`. Now my blog run without API and the previous path working fine.

I need to have the same path with the API, then I've created this api view:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def blogPost_details_apiview(request, slug_post, slug_category):
    try:
        object = BlogPost.objects.get(slug_post=slug_post, slug_category=slug_category) 
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"Error": {
            "code": 404,
            "message": "Article not found!"
        }},
        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = BlogPostListSerializer(object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this is the code in urls.py:  `path('<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_post>/', views.blogPost_details_apiview, name="details-blogpost"),`

I see this error:

> FieldError at
>   /api/blog/gis/corso-applicativo-di-base-sistemi-informativi-territoriali/
>   Cannot resolve keyword 'slug_category' into field. Choices are:
>   attachment, attachment_id, category, category_id, contents,
>   description, draft, header_image, highlighted, id, publishing_date,
>   slug_post, tags, timestamp, title, updating_date

What I've wrong?
I'm using Django 2.2

EDIT:
**models.py**

```
class CategoryBase(models.Manager):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50unique=True)
    slug_category = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):  
        return reverse("single_blogcategory", kwargs={"slug_category": self.slug_category})

class BlogPost(models.Manager):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    slug_post = models.SlugField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    header_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="related_blogcategory")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(BlogTag,related_name="related_blogtag", verbose_name="Tag")     
    attachment = models.ForeignKey(FileUpload, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="related_attachment", null=True, blank=True)
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updating_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_blogpost", kwargs={
                                                "slug_post": self.slug_post,
                                                "slug_category": self.category.slug_category,
                                                })
```

Comment: Please add the `BlogPost` model to the post. It looks like `slug_category` is not a field in this model.

Comment: @AKS now you can see the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the posted model, the `slug_category` is not on `BlogPost` but on `Category`. Please change your code to:

```
object = BlogPost.objects.get(
    slug_post=slug_post,
    category__slug_category=slug_category,
)
```

Notice that in second line, we lookup the `slug_category` on the `category` fields which is connected through foreign key.

Comment: I've forgot the connection with category... Now it run thank you! :)